# Simple C++ Game Simulator - No matching function for call

Tags: c++, function

I am writing a very simple game simulator (does not use classes). From the main() function, I successfully access one of my functions, but another function call throws the error: 'No matching function for call to simGame'.
Any ideas why this is happening?
Code:

```
...


float rollDice() {
    default_random_engine randomGenerator(time(NULL));
    uniform_real_distribution<float> rollDice(0.0f, 1.0f);

    float roll = rollDice(randomGenerator);

    return roll;
}

string simGame(string p1, string p2, int p1Health, int p2Health, int p1Attack, int p2Attack) {
    // Game State
    bool gameOver = false;
    float attack = rollDice();

    int pl1 = 0;
    int pl2 = 1;
    int turn = pl1;

    int defenderHealth = p2Health;
    int attackerAttack = p1Attack;


    while ((p1Health > 0) && (p2Health > 0)) {
        if (attack > 0.3) {
            defenderHealth -= attackerAttack;
        }
        turn = -turn + 1;
        if (turn == 0) {
            defenderHealth = p2Health;
            attackerAttack = p1Attack;
        } else {
            defenderHealth = p1Health;
            attackerAttack = p2Attack;
        }
    }

    turn = -turn + 1;
    if (turn == 0) {
        return p1;
    } else {
        return p2;
    }
    return 0;
}

int setHealth(int botNum, int botHealth) {
    int totalHealth = botNum * botHealth;
    return totalHealth;
}

int main() {

    // bot types
    int drWhosAndCompanions;
    int ricksAndMortys;


    // Attributes
    int rmHealth = 10;
    int dcHealth = 15;
    int rmAttack = 15;
    int dcAttack = 10;

    int totalRMHealth;
    int totalDocHealth;

    cout << "How many Ricks and Mortys?" << endl;
    cin >> ricksAndMortys;
    cout << "How many Dr Whos and Companions?" << endl;
    cin >> drWhosAndCompanions;

    // Starting Vals
    totalRMHealth = setHealth(ricksAndMortys, rmHealth);
    totalDocHealth = setHealth(drWhosAndCompanions, dcHealth);

    cout << "You have chosen " << ricksAndMortys << " Ricks and Mortys and " << drWhosAndCompanions << " Dr. Whos and Companions.\n";
    string res;
    res = simGame(ricksAndMortys, drWhosAndCompanions, rmHealth, dcHealth, rmAttack, dcAttack);

    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its simple

Your function definition has this prototype

```
simGame(string, string, int, int, int, int);
```

But you are passing

```
simGame(ricksAndMortys, drWhosAndCompanions, rmHealth, dcHealth, rmAttack, dcAttack);
```

In which ricksAndMortys and deWhosAndCompanions are int type

So change their data type to string
In main function

```
// bot types 
int drWhosAndCompanions;
int ricksAndMortys;
```

Should be

```
// bot types 
string drWhosAndCompanions;
string ricksAndMortys;
```

Comment: I can't believe that got by me - coming from JS and Python so static typing is a bit disorienting.

Comment: Yeah. It happened to me also :)